# Compare and filter two dataframes based on first and last row

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the total time between dataframe 1 and 2. However, if I extract the data and the process is already running (so startdate already happened) I get an error in pandas due to columns that are not the same length.

I would like to check the following two conditions, but I am not sure how to do this using iloc (or any other statement):

1. Check the first row against each other: if[row 1 of df1] > [row 1 of df2], then: delete row 1 of df1; else: leave as is.
2. Check the last row against each other: if[last row of df1] < [last row of df2], then: delete last row of df2; else: leave as is.

The amount of rows in the dataframe is always different, so this needs to be flexible.

Thanks in advance!

```
df1 = {
  "Startdate": ["2020-06-07 00:00", "2020-08-07 00:01", "2020-10-11 00:35", "2020-11-24 00:03"]

df2 = {
  "Stopdate": ["2020-06-06 12:00", "2020-08-06 11:01", "2020-10-10 00:20"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say dataframes but your example has plain distionaries.
Dealing with dictionaries, this should help you:

```
df1 = {
  "Startdate": ["2020-06-07 00:00", "2020-08-07 00:01", "2020-10-11 
00:35", "2020-11-24 00:03"]}

df2 = {
  "Stopdate": ["2020-06-06 12:00", "2020-08-06 11:01", "2020-10-10 
00:20"]}

if df1['Startdate'][0] > df2['Stopdate'][0]:
    df1['Startdate'].pop(0)

if df1['Startdate'][-1] < df2['Stopdate'][-1]:
    df2['stoptdate'].pop()
```

WIth dataframes, this should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  "Startdate": ["2020-06-07 00:00", "2020-08-07 00:01", "2020-10-11 
00:35", "2020-11-24 00:03"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  "Stopdate": ["2020-06-06 12:00", "2020-08-06 11:01", "2020-10-10 
00:20"]})

if df1.loc[0,'Startdate'] > df2.loc[0,'Stopdate']:
    df1 = df1.drop(0)

if df1.loc[df1.index[-1],'Startdate'] < 
df2.loc[df2.index[-1],'Stopdate']:
    df2 = df2.drop(df2.index[-1])
```